# Wordpress desktop app shows blank screen

Tags: installation

I'm new two WordPress so this may be simple.  Something I did caused the desktop application screen to go blank and stop/restarting the application did not fix it.

**How can I fix the WordPress.com Desktop App?  I'm running version 2.8.0.**

To fix this I've tried using the desktop app itself, the menu choices while they work they don't "fix the blank screen".

I've logged onto the wordpress.com website with my "admin" login and it works correctly (no blank screen) and I made changes to the site and everything seems to work there, but again the desktop application shows a blank screen.

I'm running on a Windows 10 system and downloaded the WordPress desktop application ([WordPress.com desktop app](https://apps.wordpress.com/d/windows/)) from WordPress.com.  I activated a free blog subscription (on WordPress.com) and was playing around.  I could make changes and when I saved changes in the desktop app, I could refresh my browser and see my wordpress site at mysite.wordpress.com get updated.

I started experimenting with changing the themes and selected a "premium" one and the desktop application screen went blank.

I did searches and found suggestions about clearing browser cache, making sure cookies and scripting is enabled, making sure anti-virus isn't blocking things but I don't think these apply to the desktop application.

**(Q) Do the browser cache, and other settings matter if I'm using the WordPress desktop application?**  If so which browser?  IE, Firefox, or Chrome?

Answer (score -1):

I noticed there was a newer version of Wordpress Desktop App (v3.1.0) and when I tried to install it the installer said it could not update a file.  I know from previous experience that this often means that the wordpress desktop app was still running in the background (even after I closed it).  To me this was a sign that something in the application was hung or not working correctly.

So I rebooted to make sure the app was no longer running and re-installed the latest version and the installation worked fine.

When I stated the Wordpress Desktop App, the problem (blank screen) was fixed, and I can now edit my Wordpress site again.

I'm sharing all of the things I did because I'm not positive which step fixed it.